# How to bind a custom route to a method of a controller via yaml without triggering an automatic query from api-platform and symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, controller, api-platform.com

- I have a simple symfony project base on api-platform.
- I have an entity named "MyEntity".
- I have a ressource yaml config file to tell api-platform how my entity to be query via api call .
- In the yaml, I added a route named `exportcsv` exposed as `export`, it will be called by my front with this url : `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/myentitys/export`.
- This route is mapped to call the export method from MyEntity controller.
- In MyEntity controller I have a method named `export` and I will do nothing except dumping a sentence then die ( `dd('why?!');` ).

### Expected behavior:

- call the export url
- Nothing should be done on the server/database, and the front will just receive a dump of the string `why?!`

### Actual behavior:

- call the export url
- execute a query on the table'db named myentity
- then receive a dump of the string `why?!`

I discovered the query when I added data to my table.
Performance went longer and longer as I added more data on the table.
I would never reach the `Why?!` at some point.
I checked my database, and saw that a select all on the myentity table were active.
I searched a bit on the documentation, the only thing I could find is :

```
pagination_partial: true
```

When adding this in the yaml, to the `export` route, it will still execute a query, but as it now paginated, it will take way less time.

---

### My question is:

**How to totatlly remove this query at all ?**

---

#### In Controller/MyEntityController.php :

```
        namespace App\Controller;
        
        use App\Entity\MyEntity;
        use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
        use Exception;
        // use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
        use Symfony\Component\Translation\Exception\NotFoundResourceException;
        use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
        use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;
        use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\NullOutput;
        use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBagInterface;
        use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
        use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
        use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\BadRequestHttpException;
        use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
        use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface;

        class MyEntityController// extends AbstractController
        {
    
        private ParameterBagInterface $params;
        private EntityManagerInterface $entityManager;
    
        public function __construct(ParameterBagInterface $params, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
        {
            $this->params = $params;
            $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        }
    
        public function export(KernelInterface $kernel): array
        {
            dd("why?!");
    }
// ...
}
```

#### In ressource/entity.yaml :

```
resources:
  App\Entity\MyEntity:
    shortName: ~
    description: ~
    attributes:
      order:
        referenceCafHuissier: asc
        montantEcheance: asc

      # security: 'is_granted("ROLE_USER")'
      normalization_context:
        groups: ['myentity:read']
      denormalization_context:
        groups: ['myentity:write']
    properties:
    ...
    collectionOperations:
    ...
      exportcsv:
        security: 'is_granted("ROLE_MYENTITY_ADMIN")'
        # pagination_partial: true
        method: 'GET'
        path: '/myentity/export'
        controller: 'App\Controller\MyEntityController::export'
        openapi_context:
          summary: Export CSV
          parameters: []
          responses:
            '200':
              description: Génération réussi de l'export CSV
              content:
                application/json:
                  schema:
                    type: object
                    properties:
                      type:
                        type: string
                        description: mime-type du fichier.
                      content:
                        type: string
                        description: Base64 du contenu du fichier.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you're talking about is most likely made by the `ReadListener`.

To disable it, set the `read` property to `false`, as explained [here](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/events/#built-in-event-listeners) :

```yaml
collectionOperations:
    exportcsv:
        method: get
        path: /pensions/export
        # ...
        read: false
```